# Eclipse syntax highlighting for GLSL on dark theme

Tags: eclipse, plugins, themes

I just downloaded the [Eclipse Shaders plugin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/glshaders/) to highlight GLSL code, but I use a dark theme and the syntax highlighter is designed for a light theme.

Is there a way to switch the highlighter to a dark theme compatibility mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just find out.

For those who would have the same problem, just go in Preferences -> Shaders Preferences -> Shaders Editor Preferences
Then you can choose the colors that you want.